# JQuery Chosen: Clicking on a n OPTGROUP must select all options inside it

Tags: jquery, optgroup, jquery-chosen

In the jquery chosen plugin, is there any way in which all the options get selected (chosen) when we click on their parent optgroup.

```
<select id = "country-select">
    <optgroup label="Country1">
        <option value = "city1">City1 </option>
        <option value = "city2">City2 </option>
        <option value = "city3">City3 </option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Country2">
        <option value = "city3">City3 </option>
        <option value = "city4">City4 </option>
        <option value = "city5">City5 </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

And, in the jquery I have, 
    $("#country-select").chosen();

Now, this is rendered using jquery chosen plugin. 
I need, that if I click on the optgroup labeled "Country1", all cities under it (ie. city1, city2, city3) must get selected (chosen).

Comment: Yea we need some sample code to help you further.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the sample code.